# Происхождение слова "здоровье".

Tags: этимология

Чудится тут родство *ЗДанию*, *ЗоДчему*...
*Здоровый* = стройный, выстроенный. Насколько верно такое предположение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ЗДОРОВЫЙ - похожий на дерево (по высоте/крепости), общеславянское, от dorvo - дерево,  та же основа, что и в слове "драть" (первоначальное значение - "выдранное").

ЗДАНИЕ - заимствовано из ст.-сл., производное от зьдати - строить, создавать, зьдъ - глина.

ЗОДЧИЙ - суф. производное от зьдати.

Comment: Получается, предки деревья не растили, а только драли, и строили исключительно из глины...

Спасибо за ответ )))